# Updating PHP with custom configuration options

Tags: php

Let's suppose i have built php with `./configure --enable-safe-mode --disable-cgi` etc. Is it possible to update php without loosing current configuration options? I know i could save them into a text file and bla bla but i am interesting in modifying php source files so i could **compile ONLY php modules that i need**. (eg. I don't need gd, tar, pgsql, mcrypt - functions that i'll *never* use. Why should i compile them?)

*(sorry for bad english, not from uk/us)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, what you're going for isn't possible.  That said, you can see the command line options that your version of PHP was build with in the `phpinfo()` output, so you could just copy and paste it across.

Other than that, use a package manager! :)

Comment: Than's ok but what about building only needed php modules?